# python opencv2 record screen

Tags: python, record, codec, screen-capture, python-mss

I am trying to make a screen recorder using python opencv along with the mss library.
I can not get it to record a video. Whenever I stop the application - the file size becomes static such as sizes as for example 6kB - depending on the codec I used.

I have read that the capture must be the same size as the screen resolution which it is - but it still does not record.

I have also tried to use various codecs such as *'MP4V' but whatever I try - it does not save a proper recording.

I am using a MAC with a m1 processor if that matters.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import glob
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip
from mss import mss
from PIL import Image
import time

fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('outpute.avi', fourcc, 60, (2560,1600))

with mss() as sct:
    
    # Part of the screen to capture
    monitor = {"top": 0, "left": 0, "width": 2560, "height": 1600}

    while "Screen capturing":
        last_time = time.time()

        # Get raw pixels from the screen, save it to a Numpy array
        img = np.array(sct.grab(monitor))

        # Display the picture
        cv2.imshow("OpenCV/Numpy normal", img)

        # Write the image
        out.write(img)
    
        print("fps: {}".format(1 / (time.time() - last_time)))

        # Press "q" to quit
        if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord("q"):
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            break
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After debugging I noticed that monitor values has to be divided by 2 in order to work. No idea why this is the case - but I debugged it and saw that this was the case.

I also realized that I had to convert from BGR to RGB before I am writing it to a video file. Otherwise it won't work.

I also changed the format, but it was not part of the problem I do not believe.

Here is the working code

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import glob
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip
from mss import mss
from PIL import Image
import time
import pyautogui

SCREEN_SIZE = tuple((2880,1800))

fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MP4V')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.mp4', fourcc, 60, (SCREEN_SIZE))

with mss() as sct:
    
    # Part of the screen to capture
    monitor = {"top": 0, "left": 0, "width": 1440, "height": 900}
    
    while True:
        last_time = time.time()

        img = np.array(sct.grab(monitor))
 
        img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

        out.write(img)

        print("fps: {}".format(1 / (time.time() - last_time)))

        if cv2.waitKey(2) & 0xFF == ord("q"):
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            break
```

(Ignore the extra libraries I added)

Comment: It is not perfect as colors are differing from original but it works, edited it to delete unused improts and fix codecs value

Comment: answer is flawed. `waitKey()` will never return anything but `-1` because there are no calls to OpenCV APIs that would open a window.